# Python class variables and instance variables confusion

Tags: python, variables

I am getting some slightly unexpected behaviour regarding the following code:

```
class MyClass(object):
   value = 5

object1 = MyClass()
object2 = MyClass()

print object1.value #This displays 5
print object2.value #This displays 5
print MyClass.value #This displays 5 

#So far so good

object1.value = 6

print object1.value #This displays 6
print object2.value #This displays 5
print MyClass.value #This displays 5

#Still good, but the confusing part is coming up...

MyClass.value = 10

print object1.value #This displays 6. I was expecting it to be 10!
print object2.value #This displays 10
print MyClass.value #This displays 10
```

As you can see, I am changing the instances version of the variable, and get expected results. But when I then change MyClass.Value to 10 I am expecting it to change the value for ALL instances. But perhaps my understanding is not correct.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

At first, `object1` and `object2` are both instances of `MyClass` without any instance-specific variables. Then you change `object1.value`. It’s still a member of `MyClass`, but when you ask for `object1.value` you get 6 because it doesn’t look at `MyClass`’s value once it sees it has its own. This gives the expected behavior so far.

When you change `MyClass.value` to 10, any time you look up `MyClass.value` you get 10. This happens when you look it up directly, or via `object2`. However, `object1` still has its own `value`, since you set it to 6. So when you ask for `object1.value`, it looks up `value` in `object1` and sees 6. It doesn’t notice that `MyClass`’s version changed.

This doesn’t happen for `object2` because it doesn’t have an associated `value`; lookup fails in `object2`, so it tries looking up `object2.__class__.value`. Since `object2` is an instance of `MyClass`, `object2.__class__` is `MyClass`, and it gives 10.

If you were to say `del object1.value`, then look up `object1.value`, you’d get 10 from `MyClass`, just like with `object2`.

Answer (score 1):

What happens under the hood is that, when you assign an *instance* attribute, that instance's private dictionary (`__dict__`) gets updated, but not the class's `__dict__`. The former takes precedence for a look-up of the requested attribute, and if it can't be found (in the first few lines, and always for `object2`), the class's `__dict__` is used to look up the attribute.

Specifically:

> **Attribute assignments and deletions update the instance’s dictionary, never a class’s dictionary.** If the class has a `__setattr__()` or `__delattr__()` method, this is called instead of updating the instance dictionary directly.

(Emphasis mine. From [the Python documentation on the standard type hierarchy in the data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy); you'll need to find the subsection "Class instances", second paragraph. The paragraph before it deals with the instance attribute look-up order. The whole subsection and the one before, "Custom classes", may be good to read to get the concept; perhaps a few times, as it is somewhat condensed.)

---

What often helps me to understand what is going on underneath, is to print the ids and (in this case) `__dict__` attributes of the relevant instances, class and attributes. The id is not a real guarantee you're seeing the same object, but has generally worked for me when using CPython.

Your code, adjusted to print this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

class MyClass(object):
    value = 5

object1 = MyClass()
object2 = MyClass()

print(object1.value, id(object1.value), object1.__dict__)
print(object2.value, id(object2.value), object2.__dict__)
print(MyClass.value, id(MyClass.value), MyClass.__dict__)

object1.value = 6
print(object1.value, id(object1.value), object1.__dict__)
print(object2.value, id(object2.value), object2.__dict__)
print(MyClass.value, id(MyClass.value), MyClass.__dict__)

MyClass.value = 10
print(object1.value, id(object1.value), object1.__dict__)
print(object2.value, id(object2.value), object2.__dict__)
print(MyClass.value, id(MyClass.value), MyClass.__dict__)
```

and the output I get (with a few extra newlines and spaces inserted for reading comfort):

```
5 4325640816 {}
5 4325640816 {}
5 4325640816 {'__doc__': None, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'MyClass' objects>, 
    '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'MyClass' objects>, 
    '__module__': '__main__', 'value': 5}

6 4325640848 {'value': 6}
5 4325640816 {}
5 4325640816 {'__doc__': None, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'MyClass' objects>, 
    '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'MyClass' objects>, 
    '__module__': '__main__', 'value': 5}

6 4325640848 {'value': 6}
10 4325640976 {}
10 4325640976 {'__doc__': None, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'MyClass' objects>, 
    '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'MyClass' objects>, 
    '__module__': '__main__', 'value': 10}
```

The ids will vary per run and system, and conveniently here, `'value'` is always printed last in the `MyClass.__dict__`, but you can see which attributes change and which are effectively the same, and how the `__dict__` attribute gets updated.

(Note: do *not* modify the `__dict__` attribute yourself. Generally, don't use it in any way, not to read from either. Let other built-in methods and functions handle that.)